# Класс collections.OrderedDict

Tags: python, python-2.x

Объяснитье, пожалуйста, на пальцах, что тут происходит:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {'banana': 3, 'apple':4, 'pear': 1, 'orange': 2}
a = OrderedDict()
a['one'] = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
a['two'] = OrderedDict([('apple', 4), ('banana', 3), ('orange', 2), ('pear', 1)])
a['three'] = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))
a['four'] = OrderedDict([('pear', 1), ('orange', 2), ('banana', 3), ('apple', 4)])
a['five'] = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: len(t[0])))
a['six'] = OrderedDict([('pear', 1), ('apple', 4), ('orange', 2), ('banana', 3)])

print type(a)
for key, value in a.items():
    print str(key) + ":  " + str(value)
```

Что делает функция `key` ?

Comment: `key` упоминается 5 раз и ни разу в виде функции. Трижды в виде параметра функции `sorted`, (в качестве значения параметра каждый раз передаются разные функции) и два раза в качестве локальной переменной в цикле `for`. О Каком именно `key` вы спрашиваете?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]) 
#вернёт массив, состоязщий из tuple( key, value ) словаря d, отсортированный по ключу (первому элементу tuple)

sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1])
#как и в предыдущем случае, но сортировка будет идти
# по второму элементу tuple (по значению)

sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: len(t[0]))
# сортировка по длине ключа

#a.items возвращает массив tuple [('one', OrderedDict(...) ), ('two',-//-), ('three',-//-) ...]
for key, value in a.items(): # здесь key это ключ из словаря a 
    print str(key) + ":  " + str(value)
```